# Auto run a jar file from usb drive

Tags: jar, usb, autoplay

I have an runnable jar file in my USB drive. I need to auto-launch that jar, when the USB drive is plugged in to the system. I use Windows 7. I used autorun.inf to launch the jar file. But it doesn't work. Any suggestions please.

autorun.inf

```
[Autorun]
Open=myjar.jar
Action=Start portable apps
```

Comment: Configuring USB drives to auto-run when plugged in is a bad practice. Setting up your computers to *allow* random USB drives to auto-run code when plugged in is [even worse](http://www.technewsworld.com/story/70699.html).

Answer (score 1):

### SEE UPDATE BELOW

The easiest way to do it would be to write a batch file (or a command file) to autorun.
that contains something like:

runjar.bat

```
 java -jar myjar.jar
```

and in your autorun.inf do something like:

```
[Autorun]
open=runjar.bat
action=start portable apps
```

### UPDATE

AAAH the problem is that Windows 7 has removed the support for autorun.inf.... See [Autorun.inf Does Not Work In Windows 7 Anymore](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/autorun-inf-does-not-work-in-windows-7-anymore/)

Comment: Thanks for response. But it didn't work. It just show the autoplay window to select for options.

Comment: Hmmm.. I too found that. But this also not working in windows XP also.